# Syntax: The use of round brackets () in front of a method call

Tags: c#, syntax

I was hoping to get some clarity on the use of () before the call of a method (applies to class,struc, etc as well). Firstly I don't know what the action is called so having trouble in pinpointing where to start reading on it, and secondly if you have some explanation on why one would use this that would be great.

In the example below I am interested in the (TestClassRemoting) that is called in front of the Activator.Getobject(...) method.

Example

```
TestClassRemoting test = (TestClassRemoting)Activator.GetObject(someType,someString);
```

Now in the scripts, TestClassRemoting is just a class defined with a Text method that will print a string.

Comment: [Casting and Type Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

Comment: THat's an explicit cast - you're telling the code to cast the `Object` returned from `Activator.GetObject` to a type of `TestClassRemoting`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Comment: Ok great. Thanks! So if I understand it correctly, you use an explicit cast when you will lose information when converting from one type to another (Double --> Int).

In the above example TestClassRemoting is a derived class that uses MarshalByRefObject to inherit from (did not mention it, but sits in the creating of the TestClassRemoting class code). Activator.GetObject(...) is a base class that does not have the inheritance properties of MarshalByRefObject, and so one needs to explicitly tell the compiler that you want to convert the output of  Activator.GetObject(...) to TestClassRemoting.

Comment: Cast syntax `(T)expr` is used for many different conversions. The conversion from `object` to `TestClassRemoting` is an explicit reference conversion. `TestClassRemoting` is a class (reference type) whose base class, or base class of base class etc., is `object`. The C# compiler sees that the expression has compile-time type `object`. The cast tells the compiler that the actual type (run-time type) is really `TestClassRemoting` (or some derived type). This is a downcast. The conversion in the opposite direction, from `TestClassRemoting` to `object`, is an implicit one. That is an upcast.

Comment: However, the explicit conversion from `double` to `int` is a *numeric* conversion. Those are not reference types or classes, and `int` is not a base class of `double`. This conversion might lose information, and that is the reason why the language designers made the conversion explicit. The only similarity to `object`→`TestClassRemoting` is the fact the the conversion is explicit.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen. Thanks for the explanation related to the subtitles involved. [Explicit reference conversions][1].

  [1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691291(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in languages like c# and java explicit type conversions are done by specifying the type the data should be converted to inside () brackets. so in your case the object returned by the Activator.GetObject is converted to type TestClassRemoting.

find more info here,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion